# How can I stop tick box inputs from emptying when I submit a form using php?

Tags: php

I'm using the following code for a series of check-boxes.
How can I change the code to  prevent the checkboxes from emptying when user submits the form.

```
    <?php
$services = array(
    'Tree Felling',
    'Height Reduction',
    'Crown Thinning',
    'Deadwooding/Ivy Removal',
    'Stump Grinding',
    'Other'
);
foreach ($services as $option) {
?>
 <label><input id="<?= $option ?>" type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php
    if ($_POST['services'] == $option) {
        echo 'CHECKED';
    }
?> value="<?= $option ?>" /><?= $option ?></label>
<?
}
?>
```

I tried this - but It didn't work out.  Am I on the right lines?

```
    <?php
$services = array(
    'Tree Felling',
    'Height Reduction',
    'Crown Thinning',
    'Deadwooding/Ivy Removal',
    'Stump Grinding',
    'Other'
);
foreach ($services as $option) {
?>
 <label><input id="<?= $option ?>" type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="<?= $option ?>" /><?= $option ?></label>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to see if $_POST['services'] is available via isset() (basically that the form's been submitted) and check to see if that service is in the array using in_array(). This worked for me:

```
<?php
$services = array(
'Tree Felling',
'Height Reduction',
'Crown Thinning',
'Deadwooding/Ivy Removal',
'Stump Grinding',
'Other'
);
foreach ($services as $option) {
?>
<label><input id="<?= $option ?>" type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php
    if ( isset($_POST['services']) and in_array($option, $_POST['services']) ) {
    echo 'CHECKED';
    }
?> value="<?= $option ?>" /><?= $option ?></label>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant that was perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the form submission is in the same page, you can get the value (if it's checked), and add it to the `input` with an `if` statement.

Otherwise, if you want that some of thouse checkboxes are checked, and other ones no, you can put an array inside, like:

```
$services = array(array("Name service 1", "checked"), array("Name service 2", "")); //leaving empty thouse you don't want checked.
```

Hope I helped you!

Comment: The form is on the same page. No boxes should be ticked when the form loads.  If the user ticks three of the six boxes and then submits the form, the three boxes would need to remain ticked.